# What does Reed's/Sugarcane's age determine?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While playing Minecraft with the `F3` info screen page up I looked at some sugarcane and saw the age.  It confused me because the ages were completely random.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I thought I saw a pattern because most the full grown 3 sugarcane high ones said age 0, but as I continued to look some two high ones also said age 0.

What does the age determine for sugarcane?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it's the growth cycle ticks completed, after it reaches a certain value the sugarcane will attempt to "grow" a new sugarcane block above it